# Problema de interbloqueos y concurrencia Productor Consumidor Java

Tags: java

Llevo ya dándole vueltas a este problema durante un par de semanas y siempre tengo algún error en la concurrencia de los hilos o que uno acabe y el otro no, interbloqueos, etc. Posteo aquí el enunciado resumido y mi código por si alguien se le ocurre porque no puedo solucionar los problemas mencionados. Muchas gracias.

---

*El ejército español, que contiene la friolera de 100 soldados (100 hilos), se prepara para la guerra tras la invasión de marcianos ocurrida durante estos días. Para ello, los soldados necesitan una serie de armas que se van guardando en un cofre. El cofre tiene capacidad para 10 armas, que además están numeradas con el identificador de cada soldado para el que dicha arma va destinada. El armero irá situando en el cofre las armas conforme vayan llegando desde la fábrica a las instalaciones de nuestro ejército. 
De esta manera, el cofre se irá llenando de armas que irán recogiendo soldado con la particularidad de que el armero deberá parar de poner armas en el cofre si éste se encuentra lleno en este momento, así como el soldado correspondiente no podrá recoger su arma si está vacío el cofre.*

```
public class Armero extends Thread{

    private int id_arma;

    private Cofre co;

    /**
     * Get the value of co
     *
     * @return the value of co
     */
    public Cofre getCo() {
        return co;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of co
     *
     * @param co new value of co
     */
    public void setCo(Cofre co) {
        this.co = co;
    }

    public Armero(Cofre co) {
        id_arma=0;
        this.co=co;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of id_arma
     *
     * @return the value of id_arma
     */
    public int getId_arma() {
        return id_arma;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of id_arma
     *
     * @param id_arma new value of id_arma
     */
    public void setId_arma(int id_arma) {
        this.id_arma = id_arma;
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            id_arma=i;
            co.depositarArma(id_arma);
            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("El armero no puede irse a dormir");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
 public class EjercitoEspañol {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cofre co= new Cofre();
        Armero a = new Armero(co);
        Soldado s[]=new Soldado[100];


        a.start();

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            s[i]=new Soldado(i,i,co);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            s[i].start();
        }
        /*for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            try {
                s[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("El soldado " + i + " no puede esperar");
            }
        }*/

        /*try {
            a.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("El armero no puede completar la tarea");
        }*/
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Soldado extends Thread{

    private int id_soldado;
    private int id_arma;
    private Cofre co;

    public Soldado(int id_soldado,int id_arma,Cofre co) {
        this.id_soldado = id_soldado;
        this.id_arma=id_arma;
        this.co=co;
    }


    /**
     * Get the value of id_soldado
     *
     * @return the value of id_soldado
     */
    public int getId_soldado() {
        return id_soldado;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of id_soldado
     *
     * @param id_soldado new value of id_soldado
     */
    public void setId_soldado(int id_soldado) {
        this.id_soldado = id_soldado;
    }

    public void run(){
        co.retirarArma(id_soldado, id_arma);
        try {
            sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("El soldado " + id_soldado + " no puede irse a dormir");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Cofre {

    private static int[] cofre;

    private static int cantidadArmas;

    private static boolean lleno;

    private static int pos;

    private static boolean vacio;


    /**
     * Get the value of pos
     *
     * @return the value of pos
     */
    public static int getPos() {
        return pos;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of pos
     *
     * @param pos new value of pos
     */
    public static void setPos(int pos) {
        Cofre.pos = pos;
    }

    public Cofre() {
        cofre=new int[10];
        for(int i=0;i<cofre.length;i++){
            cofre[i]=-1;
        }
        cantidadArmas=0;
        lleno=false;
        vacio=true;
        pos=0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of lleno
     *
     * @return the value of lleno
     */
    public static boolean isLleno() {
        return lleno;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of lleno
     *
     * @param lleno new value of lleno
     */
    public static void setLleno(boolean lleno) {
        Cofre.lleno = lleno;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of cantidadArmas
     *
     * @return the value of cantidadArmas
     */
    public static int getCantidadArmas() {
        return cantidadArmas;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of cantidadArmas
     *
     * @param cantidadArmas new value of cantidadArmas
     */
    public static void setCantidadArmas(int cantidadArmas) {
        Cofre.cantidadArmas = cantidadArmas;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of cofre
     *
     * @return the value of cofre
     */
    public static int[] getCofre() {
        return cofre;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of cofre
     *
     * @param cofre new value of cofre
     */
    public static void setCofre(int[] cofre) {
        Cofre.cofre = cofre;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of cofre at specified index
     *
     * @param index the index of cofre
     * @return the value of cofre at specified index
     */
    public static int getCofre(int index) {
        return cofre[index];
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of cofre at specified index.
     *
     * @param index the index of cofre
     * @param cofre new value of cofre at specified index
     */
    public static void setCofre(int index, int cofre) {
        Cofre.cofre[index] = cofre;
    }

    public synchronized void depositarArma(int id_arma){
        while(lleno){
            try {
                wait();
                System.out.println("El armero esta esperando");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error,el armero no puede esperar");
            }
        }
        cofre[pos]=id_arma;
        System.out.println("El armero ha depositado el arma " + id_arma + " en el cofre en la posicion " + pos);
        cantidadArmas++;
        pos++;
        if(pos==9){
            pos = pos%9;
        }
        if(cantidadArmas==9){
            System.out.println(cantidadArmas + " A ");
            lleno=true;
            vacio=false;
            notify();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void retirarArma(int id,int id_arma){
        while(vacio && cantidadArmas<=0){
            try {
                wait();
                System.out.println("El armero esta esperando");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error,el armero no puede esperar");
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<cofre.length;i++){
            if(cofre[i]==id_arma){
                System.out.println("El soldado " + id + " esta retirando su arma con id " + cofre[pos]);
                cofre[i]=-1;
                cantidadArmas--;
            }
        }
        if(cantidadArmas==0){
            System.out.println(cantidadArmas + " S ");
            lleno=false;
            vacio=true;
            notify();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un par de problemas con tu codigo actual, tal y como esta la logica de depositar y retirar armas estan en cofre, pero con los siguientes problemas:

- El cofre deberia tener capacidad para 10 armas, pero:

  - Los indices para depositar estan restringidos entre 0 y 8.

    ```
    if(pos==9){
        pos = pos%9;
    }
    ```
  - Si se depositan 9 armas se establece `lleno` en `true`

    ```
    if(cantidadArmas==9){
        System.out.println(cantidadArmas + " A ");
        lleno=true;
        vacio=false;
        notify();
    }
    ```
  - Solo se notifica a un *thread* cuando se llena el cofre, en lugar de notificar a todos los *threads* cuando **hay armas** disponibles
- El soldado solo intenta retirar su arma una vez y solo espera si el cofre esta vacio, pero no hace nada si no encuentra su arma.

  ```
  while(vacio && cantidadArmas<=0){
      try {
          wait();
          System.out.println("El armero esta esperando");
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          System.out.println("Error,el armero no puede esperar");
      }
  }
  ```
- Solo se notifica a un *thread* cuando se vacia el cofre, en lugar de notificar cuando **no esta lleno** a todos los *threads*

  ```
  if(cantidadArmas==0){
      System.out.println(cantidadArmas + " S ");
      lleno=false;
      vacio=true;
      notify();
  }
  ```

Solucionando los errores anteriores y utilizando una lista por simplicidad en lugar de un arreglo para las 10 armas, el codigo de cofre quedaria asi:

```
class Cofre {

    private List<Integer> armas;
    private int capacidadMaxima;

    public Cofre(int capacidadMaxima) {
        this.armas = new ArrayList<>(capacidadMaxima);
        this.capacidadMaxima = capacidadMaxima;
    }

    public boolean isLleno() {
        return armas.size() == capacidadMaxima;
    }

    public boolean isVacio() {
        return armas.isEmpty();
    }

    public int getCantidadArmas() {
        return armas.size();
    }

    public synchronized void depositarArma(int id_arma) {
        while (isLleno()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("El armero esta esperando que se vacie el cofre");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error, el armero no puede esperar");
            }
        }
        armas.add(id_arma);
        System.out.println("El armero ha depositado el arma " + id_arma + " en el cofre. Cantidad armas: " + getCantidadArmas());
        //notificar a todos los threads que hay armas disponibles
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void retirarArma(int id_soldado, int id_arma) {
        while (isVacio() || !intentarRetirarArma(id_soldado, id_arma)) {
            try {
                System.out.println("El soldado " + id_soldado + " no encontro su arma. Cantidad armas: " + getCantidadArmas());
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error, el soldado no puede esperar");
            }
        }
    }

    private synchronized boolean intentarRetirarArma(int id_soldado, int id_arma) {
        for (int i = 0; i < armas.size(); i++) {
            if (armas.get(i) == id_arma) {
                System.out.println("El soldado " + id_soldado + " esta retirando su arma con id " + id_arma);
                armas.remove(i);
                //notificar a todos los threads que se ha retirado un arma (solo al armero le interesa)
                notifyAll();
                return true; //dejar de esperar
            }
        }
        return false; //no encontramos el arma, seguir esperando
    }

}
```